# Autotool : Compiling same project using multiple configuration

Tags: build, autotools

I am setting up a project based on autotools for the first time and I need to build the project for two platform (using two different toolchains).

Currently when I want to build for one tool chain, I restart from scratch because I am not sure to fully understand how it works.
(autoconf, configure, make).

But is the autoconf / configure part required each time?
If I create two build directories, and call configure from each directory (with different flags for each one),
can I just then call make without performing all process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is the autoconf / configure part required each time? If I create two build directories, and call configure from each directory (with different flags for each one), can I just then call make without performing all process?

Autoconf is for building the (cross-platform) build system.  There is no reason to think that running the same version of Autoconf with the same inputs (your `configure.ac` and any custom macros bundled with your project, mostly) would yield different outputs.  So no, you don't need to run `autoconf` separately for each build, and in fact it is the standard Autotools model that you *not* run `autoconf` at each build.

So yes, it is absolutely natural and expected usage to create two build directories, and in each one run `configure; make`.  Moreover, if indeed you are creating separate build directories instead of building in the source directory, then you will be able to see that `configure` writes all its output to the build directory.  Thus, in that case, one build cannot interfere with another.